# how to open html file without menu bar using vb.net window application

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html

Hi I am trying to open HTML file in Firefox browser with following code

```
 Dim NewProcess As Process
 NewProcess.Start(url1)
```

by default it is opening in Firefox as my default browser is Firefox but it is opening with all tools and menu bar how can I open it without tools and menu.

how Can I use

```
window.open(url,"MyWindow","config='toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,atus=no'");
```

propery to this page

Comment: See my edit. I made an edit to my second code where your app waits until the process has opened, then waits 1,5 seconds to then close the window that you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the `-url` parameter along with that code of yours when opening a new Firefox process.

```
Dim NewProcess As Process = Process.Start("firefox.exe", "-url ""javascript:window.open('" & url1 & "','MyWindow','config=toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,atus=no');""")
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively (since this does not seem to work in all cases) you could write a temporary HTML file which when opened creates a new window per your specifications.

```
Public Const BaseWindHTML As String = "<script>window.open('<replaceurl>','MyWindow','config=toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,atus=no'); window.close();</script>"

Public Sub OpenNewWindow(ByVal URL As String)
    Dim HTMLPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), "newwindow.html")

    Using Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(HTMLPath, False)
        Writer.Write(BaseWindHTML.Replace("<replaceurl>", URL))
    End Using
    Dim fProcess As Process = Process.Start("firefox.exe", "-url """ & HTMLPath & """")
    fProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
    fProcess.CloseMainWindow()
End Sub
```

Example use:

```
OpenNewWindow("http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the "newwindow.html" is also opening with the url so two windows are opening at a time I want only a url window  to be open while with start process.

Comment: window.close() is not closing this window

Comment: @AnujaDeshpande I know you only want one window. I will try another workaround since `window.close()` does not seem to work.

Comment: I tried with the fProcess.Kill() it is killing both the browser windows.

Comment: @AnujaDeshpande : Hmmh, try replacing `fProcess.Kill()` with `fProcess.CloseMainWindow()`. I've updated the answer to that too (I'm afraid I won't be able to test this yet though).

Comment: fProcess.CloseMainWindow() is actually closing the another window which is coming without tool and menu bar.